# Which punctuation marks would you choose for an IELTS test when giving extra information?

Tags: punctuation

I wonder which are viable and perfectly safe to use in this case, which is in an IELTS test. Please suggest all viable versions if you can. Thank you so much!!

1. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts—**18% versus 6%**.
2. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts, **18% and 6% respectively**.
3. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts **(18% and 6% respectively)**.
4. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts: **18% and 6% respectively**.

Comment: I know that the second version is perfectly fine; I actually want at least one alternative to it. I only included it for the sake of adequacy.

Comment: I love the first version but many websites, not all, suggest that it's rather informal, and that deters me from using it since it doesn't seem like a safe choice for me anymore.

Answer (score 4):

They are all fine.

But try not to mix up your style.  You don't need "alternatives", you just need punctuation that works.  You say that (2) works - and it does - so stick to that.